# Unable to Instantiate hiveserver2. Error Setting up autherization

Tags: hive

I am trying to start hiveserver2 in my local hadoop instance.

I have setup hive and required hadoop services are also running. But when i try to start hiveserver2 it is failing with the below specified error.

command

```
hive --service hiveserver2 --hiveconf hive.server2.thrift.port=10000 --hiveconf hive.root.logger=INFO,console
```

Error

```
ERROR [main] session.SessionState: Error setting up authorization: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.setAuthorizerV2Config(SessionState.java:917) ~[hive-exec-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.setupAuth(SessionState.java:877) ~[hive-exec-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.applyAuthorizationPolicy(SessionState.java:1683) ~[hive-exec-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService.applyAuthorizationConfigPolicy(CLIService.java:130) ~[hive-service-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService.init(CLIService.java:114) ~[hive-service-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.hive.service.CompositeService.init(CompositeService.java:59) ~[hive-service-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.hive.service.server.HiveServer2.init(HiveServer2.java:142) ~[hive-service-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.hive.service.server.HiveServer2.startHiveServer2(HiveServer2.java:607) ~[hive-service-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.hive.service.server.HiveServer2.access$700(HiveServer2.java:100) ~[hive-service-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.hive.service.server.HiveServer2$StartOptionExecutor.execute(HiveServer2.java:855) ~[hive-service-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.hive.service.server.HiveServer2.main(HiveServer2.java:724) ~[hive-service-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221) ~[hadoop-common-2.7.6.jar:?]
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136) ~[hadoop-common-2.7.6.jar:?]
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.registerAllFunctionsOnce(Hive.java:236) ~[hive-exec-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.<init>(Hive.java:388) ~[hive-exec-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.create(Hive.java:332) ~[hive-exec-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getInternal(Hive.java:312) ~[hive-exec-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.get(Hive.java:288) ~[hive-exec-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.setAuthorizerV2Config(SessionState.java:913) ~[hive-exec-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1701) ~[hive-exec-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:83) ~[hive-exec-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:133) ~[hive-exec-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:104) ~[hive-exec-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:3600) ~[hive-exec-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3652) ~[hive-exec-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3632) ~[hive-exec-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllFunctions(Hive.java:3894) ~[hive-exec-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.reloadFunctions(Hive.java:248) ~[hive-exec-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.registerAllFunctionsOnce(Hive.java:231) ~[hive-exec-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.<init>(Hive.java:388) ~[hive-exec-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.create(Hive.java:332) ~[hive-exec-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getInternal(Hive.java:312) ~[hive-exec-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.get(Hive.java:288) ~[hive-exec-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.setAuthorizerV2Config(SessionState.java:913) ~[hive-exec-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1699) ~[hive-exec-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:83) ~[hive-exec-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:133) ~[hive-exec-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:104) ~[hive-exec-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:3600) ~[hive-exec-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3652) ~[hive-exec-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3632) ~[hive-exec-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllFunctions(Hive.java:3894) ~[hive-exec-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.reloadFunctions(Hive.java:248) ~[hive-exec-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.registerAllFunctionsOnce(Hive.java:231) ~[hive-exec-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.<init>(Hive.java:388) ~[hive-exec-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.create(Hive.java:332) ~[hive-exec-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getInternal(Hive.java:312) ~[hive-exec-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.get(Hive.java:288) ~[hive-exec-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.setAuthorizerV2Config(SessionState.java:913) ~[hive-exec-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:209) ~[hive-exec-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.open(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:480) ~[hive-exec-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:247) ~[hive-exec-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:70) ~[hive-exec-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1699) ~[hive-exec-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:83) ~[hive-exec-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:133) ~[hive-exec-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:104) ~[hive-exec-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:3600) ~[hive-exec-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3652) ~[hive-exec-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3632) ~[hive-exec-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllFunctions(Hive.java:3894) ~[hive-exec-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.reloadFunctions(Hive.java:248) ~[hive-exec-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.registerAllFunctionsOnce(Hive.java:231) ~[hive-exec-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.<init>(Hive.java:388) ~[hive-exec-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.create(Hive.java:332) ~[hive-exec-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getInternal(Hive.java:312) ~[hive-exec-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.get(Hive.java:288) ~[hive-exec-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.setAuthorizerV2Config(SessionState.java:913) ~[hive-exec-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    ... 16 more
```

I have checked the status of metastore. It is working fine. Still unable to figure out the problem

Answer (score 0):

hiveserver requires a "regular" database to store its metadata.
Did you set up one?
it supports PostgreSQL, mysql, oracle and maybe others.
if not - you'll need to install one (postgres is quiet east)
and then you'll need to create a db account (hive/hive) and configure you configuration files to use it.
I'm not sure if you need to initialize the db by running specific command, or if the first running of the hive server will initialize this metadata db.
enjoy,
doron

Comment: thanks @doron-veeder for your response. I am using mysql as the metastore and I have done the setup. Using hive i am able to create tables and load data but when i am trying to start hiveserver2 it is failing with the above error.

Comment: what is you hive-site.xml ?